# MYSQL with SELECT clause with three different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Having these 3 tables

First one, EMPLOYEE

```
//Employee
E#     ENAME         D#
-----------------------
1      ALI           1
2      SITI          2
3      JOHN          2
4      MARY          3
5      CHIRS         3
```

Second, PROJECT

```
//PROJECT
P#     PNAME        D#
-----------------------
1     Computing     1
2     Coding        3
3     Researching   3
```

Third, WORKSON

```
//WORKSON
E#     P#     Hours
--------------------
1      1       3
1      2       5
4      3       6
```

So my output should be something like

```
E#       ENAME      D#       TOTAL HOURS/W
--------------------------------------------
1         ALI       1              8
2        SITI       2              0
3        JOHN       2              0
4         MAY       3              6
5        CHIRS      3              0
```

Display 0 because the employee has no project to works on.

my currently statement using

```
SELECT E.E#,E.NAME,E.D#,NVL(sum(Hours),0) AS "TOTAL HOURS/W"
    FROM Employee E,WORKSON W WHERE E.E#=W.E# OR 
GROUP BY E.E#,E.NAME,E.D#;
```

no idea how should it select then will display all the employee not only the specific E#.
Output is displayed as if employee doesn't have any project works on it, it should be display with 0 value

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MySQL?  Please tag the question with the appropriate database.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done joining only employee and WORKSON  as

```
select
e.`E#`,
e.ENAME,
e.`D#`,
coalesce(tot,0) as `TOTAL HOURS/W`
from Employee e
left join
(
  select `E#`,
  sum(Hours) as tot
  from WORKSON
  group by `E#`
)w
on w.`E#` = e.`E#`
group by e.`E#`
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c18b/11)**

Comment: can i don't want to work with coalesce ?
got another choice? as i not clear to use that

Comment: well without coalesce  the TOTAL HOURS/W will be shown as NULL in case there is no data in the joining table, so no harm using coalesce.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `left outer join`.  The following should work in both MySQL and Oracle:

```
SELECT E.E#, E.NAME, E.D#,
       COALESCE(SUM(Hours), 0) AS "TOTAL HOURS/W"
FROM Employee E LEFT OUTER JOIN
     WORKSON W 
     ON E.E# = W.E# 
GROUP BY E.E#, E.NAME, E.D#;
```